# Past simple for an event taking place before reference time

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

> It is against this backdrop that the film **was made** and so it is a
>   little wonder that "The Great Rock'N'Roll Swindle" is the tale of the
>   way in with McLaren viewed the Sex Pistols. The writing and graphics
>   are his and his alone and the fashions are wholly his in the footage
>   filmed specifically for the film and mainly in the archive footage.
>   This is McLaren film. Throughout the period the Sex pistols were
>   active there had always been an intention to produce a film based
>   around the band. It was always part of McLaren's  master plan that the
>   Pistols were more than merely a band. In   the tradition of situanism
>   however McLaren had intended the film to be a very extreme affair and
>   indeed had begun filming using Russ Meyer, the director of such films
>   as Beyond The Valley of the Dolls (1970). McLaren's choice of Meyer as
>   a suitable director  for the Sex Pistol's film is telling. McLaren saw
>   him as '... not being a liberal'. He was a Vietnam veteran who
>   produced sordid and exploitative films and the script McLaren and
>   Meyer **came up** with reflected this. It was perhaps fortunate for
>   the public that Meyer walked out when production had barely begun

*Phil rose exposé on The Great Rock'N'Roll Swindle Repeat fanzine Autumn 1997*

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

In this passage reference time is the film :**before** it was made is past perfect and **after** is past simple:

For example in the second paragraph:
         'had always been an intention 'before the film **past perfect**
         'was active before and after '  **past simple**
         'was always that the Pistols were more than a band 'before and after 
         the film **past simple**
         'had intended and had begun 'before the film **past perfect**, but in that case the reason to use **past perfect** could have been the changing of director,in fact McLaren took Julian Temple to realise the film.
         'saw' after and before the film 
          was, produced before and after
         'came up' before the film but **past simple** Why?

Is it because if it were **past perfect**, we would understand it did it before being a veteran or is it because we are talking about a particular film ,

Comment: "In this passage reference time is the film :before it was made is past perfect and after is past simple" -- This assumption is incorrect. In the first sentence, "It is against this backdrop that the film was made and so it is a little wonder that ...", the reference time is now. In another sentence, "Throughout the period the Sex pistols were active there had always been an intention to produce a film based around the band", the period the Sex Pistols were active is the reference time.

Comment: In general, our reference time moves and changes along with the passage (not only this specific one, but any passages). I haven't read the whole passage of yours (and I couldn't find it on the web), but I think "in with" should be "in which". I'm sorry that I haven't really read your questions, which appear to be many, either.

Comment: I've tried to parse all your questions and I'm just unwilling to take and hour and try to figure out what part is what. Please parse this different like // It is against this backdrop that (a)the film was made and so (b)it is a little wonder that "The Great Rock'N'Roll Swindle" is the tale of the way in with McLaren viewed the Sex Pistols. // Then copy (a)/(b) phrases indented, then ask your question about the two phrases. Then move on to the next pair of phrases that have you stumped.

Comment: What is the question?!?!